# What specs does the "gros condo" (big capacitor) needs to have?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, rs232, ttl

I have a pair of Dynaudio Air 20 at home. Unfortunately, the cable that used to control the speakers via RS232 died. I opened the cable, and saw that it was a customized RS-232 to TTL adapter, but ending in a RJ45 (Dynaudio's TC-LINK proprietary communication).
I made a schematic out of what I can find on the Internet, plus the pictures of the internals of the cable, but I need to find the value of what is the "big capacitor" ("gros condo", C8) on the right hand side.
[image: Schematic of the circuit]

You can refer to this picture for reference :
[image: Picture of the cable currently]
(never mind, everything is broken on this PCB, I made too much experiments on it)

Also, if you see something that is not right for you (like something where it shouldn't be), feel free to add a comment ! I need to make a functional and safe board !

Thanks you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a capacitor use for power supply decoupling. A very 'standard' function where the value is no too critical. (With which I mean that in this case making it too big does not hurt).

The value depends on the quality of your supply. Looking at the size a 10uF should probably suffice.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! And do you have any advice for the board itself, if there is something strange for you ?

Comment: Advice about what?  It look like a standard PCB with a standard RS323 level convert chip. The wire soldering is rather (Humm how do I put this polity....) sub-optimal.

Comment: I know, since I'm a 1-day novice, and the original board used some sort of "plate" going around the PCB, for the ground, so I don't know how to replicate something similar in EasyEDA. But thanks again !

Comment: @ArnoD. I don't know EasyEDA, but you can probably defined "zones" or "planes" or something. Having a ground plane is (almost) always a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The "ST232" code on the IC suggests it is an ST part, and indeed the data sheet is available [here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00001703.pdf). The manufacturer suggests a 100 nF cap for decoupling, see figure 2 on the data sheet.

Comment: For some reason Maxim (TI) recommends 1µF for their classic MAX232, so I put 1µF and bought some MAX232 (the ST is only available on quote, and works exactly the same, so...)